# Eclipse-che Installation on Kubernetes

Tags: eclipse-che

Can someone provide detail steps or proper document to install eclipse-che in Kubernetes

I have deployed eclipe-che in Kubernetes cluster through chectl in aws ec2 instance with below details and I have used Auth0 configuration as 'Oauth tool'

command: "chectl server:deploy --platform k8s --che-operator-cr-patch-yaml cr-patch.yaml --domain  --skip-oidc-provider-check"

cr-patch.yaml:
apiVersion: org.eclipse.che/v2
spec:
networking:
auth:
identityProviderURL: auth0-url
oAuthClientName: clientId
oAuthSecret: clientSecret

After installation all pods running fine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCOtJ.png)

I have created application in Auth0 and configured all callback, login and logout urls. But while accessing the eclipse-che dashboard url through browser it is re-directing to Auth0 application login page, but getting 403 forbidden error while logging.

[404 Forbidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUJZq.png)